# How to squash all commits from a commit id?

Tags: git

I have *a lot* of commits on my dev branch and I want to squash them into a single commit before creating a merge request. I want to squash all commits from id: `9199ed7e53dbeeecbb9ef107e245f4d07b2ff257` including the last commit: `6177ddbf5b8e681a028abd7c512ae6ccdc86e744`

I think i need to use the `git rebase interactive` but I don't want to do some manual work for 50+ commits :/ any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case,

```
# move head to the last commit
git reset 6177ddbf5b8e681a028abd7c512ae6ccdc86e744 --hard

# move head to 9199ed7e53dbeeecbb9ef107e245f4d07b2ff257 and keep all changes in the index
git reset 9199ed7e53dbeeecbb9ef107e245f4d07b2ff257 --soft

# amend the changes into 9199ed7e53dbeeecbb9ef107e245f4d07b2ff257
git commit --amend
```

Here we can use a slightly different method,

```
# move head to the last commit
git reset 6177ddbf5b8e681a028abd7c512ae6ccdc86e744 --hard

# move head to 9199ed7e53dbeeecbb9ef107e245f4d07b2ff257's parent and keep all changes in the index
git reset 9199ed7e53dbeeecbb9ef107e245f4d07b2ff257~ --soft

# commit the changes
git commit
```

Interactive rebase can also work but it needs a bit more editing.

```
# specify 9199ed7e53dbeeecbb9ef107e245f4d07b2ff257's parent as the base
git rebase -i 9199ed7e53dbeeecbb9ef107e245f4d07b2ff257~

# modify the "pick" from the 2nd line to the last line to "s" or "squash"
# with the help of editor like vim or vs code, it's easy to edit multiple lines
# save and quit

# edit the commit message
# save and quit
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks. Issue though is that all of those commits did go to the remote branch. So when I squash locally and push the changes, I get 133 commits from the remote branch. I could delete the remote branch, recreate it and push to it again from my squashed local branch.

Comment: @PeterBoomsma If you are using Github or Gitlab, they have a feature to make a squash merge optionally when accepting the pull request/merge request, so that you don't have to squash them in the local branch. The pull request/merge request branch can keep all the history commits.